# Angularjs How to keep track of each row updated and pass that value to backend

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am very new to angularjs and need some help to update each row. Let's assume that User change any of the option from dropdown box or checkbox, i need to keep track of them and pass that data to backend whenever user click "Submit". How can i achieve that ?

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Need to update Row that I have changed';
 
 
  $scope.submitButton = function(){
    alert("please help me !!!");
  }
  
  
  
  
  $scope.cities = ["Austin",
                   "Leander",
                  "RoundRock"];
  
  $scope.data = [{check:'active',firstName:'James',lastName:'Austin',city:'Leander'},
  {check:'inactive',firstName:'Niki',lastName:'Jones',city:'Austin'},
  {check:'active',firstName:'Amy',lastName:'Parker',city:'RoundRock'}]
  


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
  
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th> City</th>
        
        
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="d.check=='active'"/>{{d.check}}</td>
          <td>{{d.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{d.lastName}}</td>
          <td><select ng-model="d.city" ng-change="showSelectValue(d.city)" ng-options="c for c in cities"></select></td>
        </tr>
       
      </tbody>
     
    </table>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submitButton()">Submit</button>
   
  </body>

</html>
```

`I am very new to Angularjs and need help with updating the each row.

Whenever user change the value either checkbox or dropdown list, I need to keep track of them and pass that data to backend whenever user click save.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Mv6ei8tcW2TJmNFelAF5?p=preview

Comment: use ng-model. check this one- 
 https://plnkr.co/edit/N4x0dSwKFQL0UkI6NgOO?p=preview . P.S. Try to change values.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Let's say, I update the dropdown value of row 2 and I wanted to get only that row, how can i achieve that ??

Comment: First solution: save everything, not just what has been modified. Second solution: use ng-change on each control to set a dirty flag on its row, save the dirty rows. Third solution: create a "backup" copy of the rows before displaying the table, compare each row to its backup copy when saving, and save only the ones that have changed.